# Constant UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

Is there any way that I can have a `UINavigationController` and have it always display the same `UIBarButtonItem` no matter how many times it is pushed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

1. Create subclass(`CustomNavigationController`) of `UINavigationController` & use it to push your view controllers.
2. In `CustomNavigationController` create `UIBarButtonItem` in `init` or in `viewDidLoad`. Add `target` & `action` to it.
3. Implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` delegates in `CustomNavigationController` and set `barButtonYouCreated` as right or left bar button item for each view controller in delegate method.

Use

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
     viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonYouCreated;
}
```

or

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UINavigationControllerDelegate` as below:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

And in this delegate method, you can check to add a barButtonItem to navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a global `UITabBarController` in`UINavigationController` that contains your push controllers, then make your push controllers`navigationbar` hidden

Answer (score 0):

Or try use a UINavigationController category, and customize the back item, so no matter how many times it's pushed, just set the same view for navigationController's back item.
Something like:

```
@implementation UIViewController (CustomNavigation)

- (void)setLeftBarButtonItem:(UIButton*)leftview
{    
    UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftview] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem; 
    [(UIButton*)self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```